# background color change on mouse position not loading until mouse moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseevent, background-color

I'm using your JS code on my website to change the color of the background based on mouse position, thanks to @j08691.

But the background color doesn't display until I move my mouse...

can you or anyone else help me with this please ?

also when using isotope there's a problem with the background color when scrolling my page... The background color is only set for the height of my screen height...

Here is the js code for the background color :

```
$(window).mousemove(function(e){
    var $width = ($(document).width())/255;
    var $height = ($(document).height())/255;
    var $pageY = parseInt(e.pageY / $width,10)+50;
    var $pageX = parseInt(e.pageX / $height,10)-100;
    $("body").css("background-color", "rgb("+$pageY+","+$pageY+","+$pageY+")");
    $(".fancy_hover_1").css("background-color", "rgb("+$pageY+","+$pageY+","+$pageY+")");

});
```

and here is my full function.js file, including the isotope Js

```
// remap jQuery to $
(function($){})(window.jQuery);


/* trigger when page is ready */
$(document).ready(function (){

    // your functions go here
    init();

    function init(){
        init_objects();
    }

    function init_objects(){

    }


});

//-------------------------------------------------- SLIDER BIO PHOTO ----------------------------------------------------//         


$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = $('.photos').length;
    $("#total").text(count);
    // set display:none for all members of ".pic" class except the first
    $('.photos:gt(0)').hide();

    // stores all matches for class="pic"
    var $slides = $('.photos');

    $slides.click(function () {
        // stores the currently-visible slide
        var $current = $(this);
        if ($current.is($slides.last())) {
            $("#current").text("1");
            $current.hide();
            $slides.first().show();
        }
        // else, hide current slide and show the next one
        else {
            $("#current").text($current.next().index()+1);
            $current.hide().next().show();
        }
    });
});



//-------------------------------------------------- ISOTOPE ----------------------------------------------------//         

$(window).load(function() {
        //isotope//
            $('.isotope').isotope({
          // options
                itemSelector : '.item',
                /*resizesContainer : true,
                resizable: true,*/
                layoutMode : 'fitRows'
        });

            });
//-------------------------------------------------- BACKGROUND-COLOR CHANGE----------------------------------------------------//  

$(window).mousemove(function(e){
    var $width = ($(document).width())/255;
    var $height = ($(document).height())/255;
    var $pageY = parseInt(e.pageY / $width,10)+50;
    var $pageX = parseInt(e.pageX / $height,10)-100;
    $("body").css("background-color", "rgb("+$pageY+","+$pageY+","+$pageY+")");
    $(".fancy_hover_1").css("background-color", "rgb("+$pageY+","+$pageY+","+$pageY+")");

});
```

and a JSfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/BegPz/

thanks a lot

Comment: You are setting backgroud-color on mousemove, then it will work only at mousemove. Is there any particular css that is not working ?

Comment: no. do I need to set in my CSS the background color ? the one that will load when page displays ?

Comment: ok thanks, I thought there was a way to get the position mouse with JS without the mouse moving.... Am I wrong ?

Comment: No, you are not wrong. But you can position your mouse anywhere in the page using JS.But the mouse move event will only work while it will move. you can try `hover` event to achieve what you need.

Comment: Sorry, but now I think you don't need to set the default css, See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can not trigger the event as object can not be passed. set default background-color on document ready. something like:

```
 $("body").css("background-color", "rgb(128,128,128)");
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BegPz/2/)**

Comment: ok thanks @Milind Anantwar ... any ideas about the isotop issue ? I don't know how to fix it.. here is the webpage where I have the problem : 
http://rockonbones.com/news/

Comment: when scrolling and moving the mouse, the background color doesn't change in the right side of my website, and there are some grey blocks... check the link above if needed, thanks for you help !

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `$(document).ready(function () {});` function, instead of defining in `$(window).mousemove(function(e){});`. And then you might not need to set any default css.

```
    $().mousemove(function (e) {
    var $width = ($(document).width()) / 255;
    var $height = ($(document).height()) / 255;
    var $pageY = parseInt(e.pageY / $width, 10) + 50;
    var $pageX = parseInt(e.pageX / $height, 10) - 100;
    $("body").css("background-color", "rgb(" + $pageY + "," + $pageY + "," + $pageY + ")");
    $(".fancy_hover_1").css("background-color", "rgb(" + $pageY + "," + $pageY + "," + $pageY + ")");

});
```

Comment: thanks @Rajesh Dhiman ! ... any ideas about the isotop issue ? I don't know how to fix it.. here is the webpage where I have the problem : rockonbones.com/news

Comment: @user2882154 Problem is here `"rgb("+$pageY+","+$pageY+","+$pageY+")"`. It will be always like `(158,158,158), (56,56,56)` etc. I mean same for all `rgb`. That will be grey always. Use a different combination like `"rgb("+$pageY+","+$pageX+","+$pageY+")"`.